# Не получается получить запрос GET через CURL

Tags: php, curl

Есть [URL страница](https://www.lechuza.ru/tovar-izmenit/?dwvar_CLASSICO__LS_color=white%20highgloss&pid=CLASSICO_LS&dwvar_CLASSICO__LS_CLASSICO_LS_Size=21) , которую я должен получить через CURL

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
```

Но в итоге получаю страницу с запросом POST (Техническая ошибка). Так же пробовал библиотеку [php-multi-curl](https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl) (addUrl). Но все ранво получаю страницу с POST запросом. Помогите пожалуйста, как я могу получить страницу с GET запросом.
file_get_contents не работает , так как HTTPS

Comment: Посмотрите php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-error.php

Comment: запрос у Вас уходит GET-ом - но! вероятно параметры урла передаются неверно. Заверните ссылке через http_build_query

Comment: скорее все курл с конкретным https не работает. пробуйте с консоли. с другого сервера пробуйте

Comment: @sterx можно отменить проверку сертификата, и тогда курл нормально примет https

Comment: example, please?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Можете подсказать , как это сделать

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); не сработало :(

Comment: @sterx в ответе пример валидного GET запроса, отрабатывает с самоподписными и с нормальными сертификатами.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $ch = curl_init('{URL}');
  $headers = array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");//изменить на нужный
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Вот валидный GET запрос, прекрасно возвращает данные даже если сертификат сервера "самоподписной" =)

Дополнено:

1) Вам нужно разобраться с авторизацией на сайте( как именно и на какой URL отправляются авторизационные данные).

2) После запроса авторизации(отправки логина и пароля) вам нужно получить авторизационную Cookie, в примере она называется "PAC"..

```
  preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $response, $matches);
  $cookies = array();
  foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
  }
```

3) Делать ваш GET запрос с этой Cookie

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8","Cookie: PAC=".$cookies['PAC']);
```

p.s.

```
<?php
  set_time_limit(100);
  $color[] = "scarlet%20red%20highgloss";
  $color[] = "shiny%20taupe";
  $color[] = "black%20highgloss";
  foreach($color[] as $col)
  {
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.lechuza.ru/tovar-izmenit/?dwvar_CLASSICO__LS_color=$col&pid=CLASSICO_LS&dwvar_CLASSICO__LS_CLASSICO_LS_Size=21&source=detail");
    $headers = array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Все равно получил страницу , которая приходит с POST запросом :(

Comment: Проверяю в Postman , если делаю GET запрос , то приходит страница с товаром , если POST , то страница с технической ошибкой

Comment: в url есть хоть 1 параметр? Что в заголовках запросов? 

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  $information = curl_getinfo($ch);
  print_r($information);

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l1qamj

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/FNqUW7pwt1GXyA
УРЛ из примера - не валидный =)

Comment: А вообще подозреваю очень сильно что нужна авторизационная кука, и без нее сайт возвращает вам верный ответ - такого ресурса нет(410).
https://yadi.sk/i/CVuyAfo-gsML2w

Comment: А как мне это можно сделать?)

Comment: Для начала разобратся какая именно кука отвечает за авторизацию, потом разобратся с авторизацией и включить куки, или самостоятельно передавать значение только одной куки. Обновляю ответ...

Comment: Вообще я это делаю без авторизации

Comment: https://www.lechuza.ru/napolnye-kashpo/classico-ls-21-chernyy-blestyashchiy/16029.html#cgid=Pflanzgefaesse&start=1 Есть товар

Comment: И у него есть цвета , попробуйте поменять цвет и получите эту ссылку. Я попробовал почистить куки и все остальное , но все равно я получаю этот товар)

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/PBqjzU3-YI-B8g да, вы правы, просто первая ссылка была не верна, и кстати да, всё прекрасно работает =)
Вот этим кодом всё сработало, смотрите настройки CURL и PHP в частности 
https://yadi.sk/i/qrlwuHY-UBy7pQ

Comment: В этом и дело , что первая ссылка работает , а вот ссылка которая введет на выбор цвета , не работает)

Comment: Хотя в браузере и в POSTMAN она отображается прекрасно

Comment: А когда пытаюсь с помощью  CURL , то почему то ссылка для смены цвета  не работает и запрашивается  с запросом POST

Comment: Вот POST - http://prntscr.com/l1qz4m , а вот GET - http://prntscr.com/l1qzeg

Comment: А CURL всегда видимо запрашивает с POST и вот не могу понять почему

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/jlPDsgG_iN_saA код прекрасно работает =)

Comment: Вот что странно. Когда я вставляю ссылку вручную, то работает , а если через массив, то не работает

Comment: Посмотрите в ответ, там пример с массивом, и он работает.